# C++ custom iterator over container based on items property

Tags: c++, iterator

I have a container of `Employees` with fields `std::string name` and `bool is_manager`. I want to iterate over container for regular and manager employees. The number of items in a container can be very large so I do not want to do a linear scan with checking `is_manager` property. Also the number of managers is very small i.e. 10 out of 100000, so doing a full scan over the container is ineffective. So I want to pre-cache the memory addresses of `Employees` with and without `is_manager==true` and have `RegularEmployeeIterator` and `ManagerEmployeeIterator`, I think this can be pre-cached and organized as a list/vector of pointers?

And I want to able to sort the container of `Employees` by `name` field and retain the ability to iterate over regulars and managers.

How to implement that in C++? Specifically, I have no idea how iterators are implemented in C++, how to define several of them for a single collection, based on property value, does my idea with caching the addresses works, etc.

Comment: I promise, your idea of "very large" has nothing to do with your computers idea of very large. (10000 is a small number for a container of one bool, and a string header)

Comment: ok actually I have tens of millions entries

Comment: There's no way to do this in a non-linear way. You must examine each and every element of your container to see if the wanted properties are as you need for the filter.

Comment: @Sengiley so, your company has 10s of millions of employees? I have my doubts. Anyways, then you should probably not be storing them as Employees objects, but as multiple separate vectors where you decompose the object; that's a common game engine technique.

Comment: As a possible workaround, you could have multiple containers, one main container for all elements. Then a set of other containers with pointers or reference (wrappers) to the original elements in the main container. One container for each "filter" you need. When you add an element to the main container, see if it matches a specific filter, and also add the reference to the corresponding filter-container.

Comment: the container is not changing after it is initialized, I don't have writes in it, only reads, so I want to pre-cache the addresses to avoid linear scan, by cherry-picking the addresses of data with certain values of a given property

Comment: This is very confusing. If, as you say,you have  "no idea how iterators are implemented" then how did this coding assignment fall from the sky? If this is a typical homework assignment, this would be given after the teacher or the instructor explained all of this, in class, and only then gave this assignment. Did your instructor simply failed to explain anything, and just said: "here, do this"? This makes no sense. Even the description is incomplete, and fails to specify which iterator category must be implemented. Can you give more background information on where all of this came from?

Comment: You could use a `std::map` which internally sorts the items. If you give the `is_manager` flag a high priority in the comparison, you can easily find all the managers.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude multiple containers are ugly, I want a single large collection, "color" the entries in advance -- red, blue, green -- which can be non-contiguous in memory and then iterate over greens

Comment: Using only a single linear container (like a `std::vector` or a `std::list`) then it's not possible to do it in a non-linear way. ***Unless*** you already know the position of the "next" element in the chain, then you can create your own internal list by having extra members that point to the next element in the chain. Then keep a reference (actual reference, pointer or index) to the first element in each chain. Then for "green" you use the first "green" element to find the next "green" element. Requires one initial iteration over all elements to set up the filter chains.

Comment: but we can address std::vector by accessing the memory addresses of its items, the idea is to store addresses of different categories in separate lists of pointers and by iterating over those specific lists of addresses get the specific entries from the main collection -- so I wonder how to nicely to code that

Comment: @JakobStark yeah, I thought about multimap with key equaling `is_manager` value

Comment: @Sengiley That is basically what I said in my first workaround: One main container, then separate "lists" of references (indexes, pointers, `std::reference_wrapper`, etc.) for each category.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah, you've got my point, the next question how to organize it in "C++ way" with containers/iterators, not in "C way" with raw pointers

Comment: It is unclear whether the expected solution is to use an auxiliary container and iterate normally over that (all those ambiguous references to "caching") or if one is supposed to implement their own custom iterator class (the "custom iterator" references), which can still be done, while meeting all the rest of the requirements, with the underlying container being a vector or a list (as long as one needs to implement only a forward or a bidirectional iterator). More information on what, exactly, this coding assignment needs to do is required in order to point to a solution.

Comment: and I want to have the ability to sort the main collection and the pointing "lists of references" updated accordingly

Comment: If you need to create your own custom iterator (instead of just iterating over the "reference" container) then I suggest you take some time to learn how iterators work, and how to create your own iterators. It's not that hard. Create an iterator that works in a way similar to the normal vector iterator, and use it to iterate over the main vector.  Then decide how you want to store the references to the main vector, using indexes (my suggestion), pointers, or something else (perhaps even `std::vector<...>::iterator`?).

Comment: [Continued...] Once you know how to store the references, you can create your "red", "green", etc. containers and populate them. This requires one initial linear loop over the main container. Now create your custom iterator class, which simply uses the iterator for the colored containers, and whose dereference operator access the element in the real main container. Lastly, create two functions to get the `begin` and `end` custom iterators from a specific colored reference container.

Answer (score 2):

> organized as a list/vector of pointers?

Whatever the problem, a list is not the data structure you need.

## 1. Unrealistic answer for a beginner, but you claim it's the problem you're solving

> ok actually I have tens of millions entries

I mean, this is very clearly a learning exercise, and you insisting that your data is 10s of millions of entries large is... mediocrily helpful, because that's the point where if access times are important, you stop storing the composite object in one container:

```cpp
std::vector<Employee> employees; //10⁷ employees
```

but would group the data according to the properties you're going to work on at the same time:

```cpp
std::vector<bool> bossiness; //10⁷ bits – std::vector<bool> has an optimization!
std::vector<std::string> names; //10⁷ std::strings
```

and as a matter of fact, if you know your data doesn't change, you wouldn't even do that, because the `names` vector is a dereferencing nightmare that wastes a lot of memory on redundant information, if you could as well just go

```cpp
std::vector<bool> bossiness; //10⁷ bits – std::vector<bool> has an optimization!
std::string all_names; // a **very** long string containing all names, one after the other
std::vector<size_t> name_begins;  // 10⁷ name beginnings; through all_names.substr(name_begins[i], name_begins[i+1]) you can access the i.th name
```

Now, to speed up looking for bosses, you just start by making a run-time encoded list of 64bit-regions in your `bossiness` vector where at least one bit is set. You could do elegant k-d trees if your problem becomes multidimensional, but at the sparsity you have, runtime encoding on machine word sizes will probably still beat the hell out of that.

But that's an optimization level you need when writing a database system or a 3D game with millions of vertices. You're learning C++. You're not writing these kinds of things, so:

## 2. Realistic answer that you didn't want when offered in the question

> i.e. 10 out of 100000

so, let's really go with a problem size of 10⁵. I.e., a small problem.

You need to do your Employee vector, and add a bosses vector:

```cpp
std::vector<Employee> employees;
std::vector<size_t> boss_indices;
```

Then you need to do your linear search once:

```
// if you know a safe and not too outlandish upper bound for the number of managers, reserve that memory once to avoid resizing the vector while filling it, as that's very expensive:
boss_indices.reserve(size_t(employees.size() * fraction_of_managers));

for(size_t idx = 0; idx < employees.size(); ++idx) {
  if(employees[idx].is_manager) {
    boss_indices.push_back(idx)
  }
}
```

congratulations, an easy to use vector indices. Indices into std::vector are just as good as pointers to elements (it's a simple pointer deref, both ways, and the additional offset is usually merged into the deref operation on any modern CPU I know), but survive the target vector being moved.

> And I want to able to sort the container of Employees by name field and retain the ability to iterate over regulars and managers.

have a class

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
struct SortableEmployee {
   const Employee* empl;
   bool operator <(const SortableEmployee& other) const {
      return std::lexicographical_compare(
          empl->name.cbegin(); empl->name.cend(),
          other.empl->name.cbegin(), other.empl->name.cend());
   }
   SortableEmployee(Employee* underlying) : empl(underlying){
   }
};
```

and put it in a `std::set` to get a sorted version that you can iterate through:

```cpp
std::set<SortableEmployee> namebook;
for(const auto& individual : employees) {
    namebook.emplace(&individual);
}
```

You can then iterate through it linearly as well

```cpp
for(const auto& sorted_empl : namebook) {
    std::cout << std::format("{}: is {}a manager\n", 
        sorted_empl.empl->name,
        sorted_empl.empl->is_manager ? "" : "not ");
}
```

Comment: Marcus, thanks for your efforts! it would take awhile to read it though... about how is it real - the elements that I deal are combinations k out of n and they are growing extremely fast! so I want to iterate over different values of k, like 2 out of n, 3 out of n, etc... hope it helps to cure your suspiciousness :)

Comment: well, that's a completely different problem and I wasted my time answering the question you asked above if that's the problem you're solving... You approach that by generating each combination when you need it, not by storing all the combinations! Hint: if you don't know the approach to a problem, don't substitute a completely different problem, because you can't know whether your substitution is sensible (otherwise you wouldn't have to ask about the approach). This is really depressing.

Comment: and it makes little sense to put them in different collections, as there are cases when I need to iterate over the whole collection of combinations, and there are cases when I need to iterate over a subcollection for given k

Comment: so: **Please ask a new question** (do not invalidate this one), and describe the problem you're actually trying to solve in there. As you notice yourself, the solutions to the question you've actually asked and the problem you actually have are different, because you asked about the wrong thing.

Comment: also,  you haven't understood my answer if you think I'm putting things in multiple collections. I'm not.

Comment: okay, I tried to be more accessible, not everyone deals with my specific problem, but I do not see very much difference to reducing my problem to the collection of objects with different property values

Comment: I don't understand. I offer a solution to the problem you ask, and you say "it's not a solution to my actual problem". Then I say, OK, if that's the case, you need to actually describe your problem, not an abstraction of your problem, as your abstraction seems to be no good at getting you the right answers!" and then you're "oh I don't see the point in that".